# How to have my Trading View alerts generate signals for Telegram

Tags: algorithm, pine-script

New User so any help is appreciated.
My signal generates the information - (Trading Pair) {{strategy.order.comment}} @{{strategy.order.price}}
An example of this is - BTCUSD Long @13500

I'm trying to get this to automatically generate a signal that I can then use to link my autotrading on telegram to.
So for example I have the signal - BTCUSD Long @13500
I want it to automatically create take profit targets, and Stoploss based on if the signal is long/short and based on the percentage of the order price. So for example:

BTCUSD
Long @13500
TP 1 - (1.003%) or 13540
TP 2 - (1.008%) or 13608
TP 3 - (1.02%) or 13770
TP 4 - (1.03%) or 13905
Stoploss - 6%

And then obviously it would have to be a positive value or negative value based on if the call is long or short.
Is this possible and thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Tradingview can send alerts with the webhooks, you have to use some 3rd party software/telegram bot to be able to catch them and translate to the format of your trading bot. See more here https://www.pinecoders.com/resources/#automated-order-execution